# Returning users from mocked ApplicationUserManager.Users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-identity, moq

I am trying to mock `ApplicationUserManager.Users` so that I can test a controller method.  My controller is

```
public class ManageController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationUserManager userManager;

    public ManagerController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    // The method being tested
    public ActionResult ListUsers()
    {
        // I want this to return my mocked user list
        var users = this.userManager.Users.ToList();

        // Do other stuff
    }
}
```

My test method is

```
[TestMethod]
public void ListUsersGet_ShouldSucceed()
{
    var users = new List<ApplicationUser>
    {
        new ApplicationUser { Id = "1", FirstName = "Test", LastName = "User" }
    }.AsQueryable();
    Mock<DbSet<ApplicationUser>> dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<ApplicationUser>>();
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<ApplicationUser>>().Setup(e => e.ElementType).Returns(users.ElementType);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<ApplicationUser>>().Setup(e => e.Expression).Returns(users.Expression);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<ApplicationUser>>().Setup(e => e.GetEnumerator()).Returns(users.GetEnumerator());
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<ApplicationUser>>().Setup(e => e.Provider).Returns(users.Provider);

    Mock<MyContext> context = new Mock<MyContext>();
    context.Setup(e => e.Users).Returns(dbSet.Object);

    Mock<UserStore<ApplicationUser>> userStore = new Mock<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(context.Object);

    var controller = new ManageController(new ApplicationUserManager(userStore.Object));

    var result = controller.ListUsers() as ViewResult;

    // Assert some stuff
}
```

When I step into my controller method, I can see that `users` is null.  It appears that `this.userManager.Users` isn't returning the users that I tried to set up in my test method.

How can I get `this.userManager.Users.ToList()` to return my test users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User manager exposes `public virtual IQueryable<TUser> Users { get; }` property. Mock the user manager dependency and give that to the controller.

```
public void _ListUsersGet_ShouldSucceed() {
    // Arrange.
    var users = new List<ApplicationUser>
    {
        new ApplicationUser { Id = "1", FirstName = "Test", LastName = "User" }
    }.AsQueryable();

    //Only mocking this because we need it to initialize manager.
    var userStore = Mock.Of<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();

    var userManager = new Mock<ApplicationUserManager>(userStore);
    userManager.Setup(_ => _.Users).Returns(users);

    var controller = new ManageController(userManager.Object);

    // Act.
    var result = controller.ListUsers() as ViewResult;

    // Assert some stuff
}
```

Check the [Quick start documentation](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get more acquainted with the mocking framework